# Apache Nifi-registry BitBucket repository?

Tags: bitbucket, apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

I am looking for version control repository in BitBucket like GitHub. I have found Nifi Git repository. But at my organization we have private account in BitBucket. My question is can I create version control repository with Apache Nifi-registry in bitbucket? There is a class (org.apache.nifi.registry.provider.flow.git.GitFlowPersistenceProvider) which is associated with Git in the providers.xml file in nifi-registry. For bitbucket which class should i use? any help, guidelines will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: bitbucket based on git. no?

Comment: @ daggett yes.Bitbucket also uses git. Yeap. it worked out for me. Had to figure out the access tocken and it started working. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't matter where the remote git repo is located, so it should work with BitBucket just like it does with GitHub. You would clone the repo from BitBucket to the server where NiFi Registry is running, and then configure providers.xml to use the local cloned repo, and enter credentials to enable pushing to remote.

It should work the same as how you would interact with the git repo from the command line. You add or modify files in the local repo, commit them, then push to remote. In this case, all these steps will be done by registry for you.

Comment: @ Bryan Bende , Would you please share the configuration of providers.xml file? I am having issue getting the access token which can automatically push the changes to bitbucket. Now i have ato manually execute the push command command to commit the changes with this"git push -u origin master" . How can I make it auto push?

Comment: I have never used BitBucket but I would assume you need to generate a token just like you do with github, I google'd BitBucket access token and found this - https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/10182/access-tokens-for-command-line-use